# Dynamically expanding field headings in crystal reports

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I have a report where I have 50+ fields and I am exporting this report from crystal to excel.  Once in excel the data columns are the proper width but the headings are truncated.  Is there a way to get the headings to dynamically expand like the data does?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the grid line tools to line up all your columns and headers?  Ensure snap to grid is on and that all headers/fields are the same size on screen.

Basically you want the crystal report in the designer to look similar to an excel report; with all the headers and fields in a grid like structure.

Crystal also produced a document many moons ago when they were owned by Seagate describing how to avoid formatting problems when exporting to excel.  Check it out [HERE](http://www.dynalivery.com/customersupport/faq/scr_exportexcel.pdf)

This helped me a load when I had to build stock reports and summaries for one of my customers.